Project is unloaded and not able to reload the project in VS 2022 17.11.5

Multiple projects in the solution is unloaded and not able to reload the projects in Visual studio 2022 17.11.5.
Showing below error while reloading.

A project with that name is already opened in the solution.

Tried multiple solutions but nothing worked.

Is this the Web API project Netframework ?

Did you change something, for example path/location of VS/ environment variables? Please try to repair your VS via opening VS Installer > More > Repair.

For this issue, i would suggest you try the following to troubleshoot:

Does this issue happen to all your solutions or the specific solution? If latter, please try to close this solution and go to the solution folder, delete the default hidden folder .vs and obj/bin folders and reopen it to test. Or do a quick test to create a new solution  to verify it.

Right click the project and remove from the solution, right click the solution name and add existing project to add this project.

Please check if you have added the following in your .csproj file. If so, please remove the section.


<ProjectTypeGuids>...</ProjectTypeGuids> 


Please check if you have installed some third-party extensions, if yes, please disable them temporarily.

Close VS and run VS as administrator to test.


I did a quick test in Visual studio 2022 17.11.5 but failed to reproduce this issue. Regardless  I'm happy to try to reproduce the issue if you can provide a minimal example.
